# Unable to add new table from InstallScheme magento2

Tags: magento2

I have created an installschema for my custom table to be created.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();
     /**
     * Create new table 'my_table1'
     */
    $table = $installer->getConnection()
        ->newTable($installer->getTable('my_table1'))
        ->addColumn(
            'id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'ID'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'product_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
            'Product ID'
        )
        ->setComment('My new table');
    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    $installer->endSetup();
   }
}
```

And I gave setup:upgrade, but Im not able to see my custom table in the database.
Where is my code wrong?

Comment: got any error while run command?

Comment: no... php bin/magento setup:upgrade ran completely, my module is enabled

Comment: I get 'My new table' as a comment in my debug.log...but no table in backend !!!

Comment: Do you mean no table in database

Comment: Yes no table in my DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the database `module_setup` table

Check their is your setup with your setup_version and schema_vesrion

Delete that row and re run below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: My module in bakend: Vendor_Module has schema and dataversion as 2.2.0.. u mean i have to delete that row and rerun?

Comment: Yes you need to delete that row and rerun command